# Как задать кодировку в curl для загрузки кириллицы?

Tags: windows, curl, flask

Апи реализован на Flask. Принимаю пост запросы. Всё работает кроме кириллических параметров. В отладчике ??? (вопросики)

```
curl -d "token=123&cid=77&f=1&i=вася" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8" -X POST http://localhost:8888/addData
```